# M1 Mac: Running Brownie Python

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, brownie

Trying to run `brownie` but running into the following issues:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so, 
2): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so: 
   code signature in (/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so) 
not valid for use in process using Library Validation: 

  Trying to load an unsigned library
```

Getting an error to load an unsigned lib for `.cpython-39-darwin.so`

Answer (score 3):

Brownie has a dependency on the `regex` module, and its most recent version installs incorrectly on M1 Macs. See [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3370#issuecomment-946012467) for more commentary.

As a workaround, you could try the following in an environment with Brownie installed:

```sh
pip uninstall regex
pip install regex==2021.9.30
# to verify this is working
brownie init new_proj
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you know if it works with pipx?

Comment: I can't say I do. I mostly stick to virtualenv. `pipx` is for packaging apps, right? I'm not sure how I'd automate this workaround. Until `regex` gets their install ready, I think you might be at the mercy of the assorted packagers.